# Wine won't use msstyles theme

Tags: wine, themes

NOTE: I have to repost this because the old one was on hold (I don't know if its admin who put it on hold and didn't notice the wine tag)

I try to install windows xp default theme so wine looks better but the theme wont show up after installing with error said

```
fixme:shell:SHCreateDirectoryExW Show system error message, creating path L"C:\\windows\\Resources\\Themes\\Luna", failed with error 183
```

[image]